# Adress Mismatch at the end point dispatcher

Tags: wcf, biztalk, webhttp

I have a WCF service which using the Web-Http Adapter through BizTalk. When I am trying to call the wcf service. I am getting the error below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
-<Code>
<Value>Sender</Value>
-<Subcode>
<Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
a:DestinationUnreachable
</Value>
</Subcode>
</Code>
-<Reason>
<Text xml:lang="en-US">The message with To 'https://biztalkt01.abc.org/ELIMS/ELIMS-CGA1/Service1.svc/?specimenid=abc001234'' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.</Text>
</Reason>
</Fault>
```

When I google for this error I can see this code needed to be added in to the service code

[    ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]

But not sure where is the service code for this service.
[image]

The above folder is wat I am seeing with respect to the service created in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ELIMS\ELIMS-CGA1.  Does the code needs to added in to any of these files or the files in the App_Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your port settings properly for the adapter.  This is not related to the WCF configuration files, but to the receive location settings in BizTalk itself.  You have to set up the `Address` and the `BtsHttpUrlMapping` elements; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj572859.aspx for more information on these particular elements.